# Equivalence of two norms in complete space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a vector space with two norms $\| \cdot \|_1$ and $\| \cdot \|_2$ such that $\| x \|_1$ $\leq$ $\| x \|_2$ for all $x \in X$. If $X$ is complete in both norms, prove they are equivalent.

Thoughts on approach: use Cauchy sequence and convergence with norm properties to get the inequality in the other direction.

Edit: I've since come up with this solution. Any feedback on correctness would be appreciated.

Proof. Let $B_i(x,r):= \{y \in X: \|y-x\|_i < r\}$. Since $\| \cdot \|_1 \leq \| \cdot \|_2$ it follows that the identity map $i:(X,\| \cdot \|_2) \rightarrow (X,\| \cdot \|_1)$ is continuous. Further we can choose an $r>0$ such that $B_1(0,1) \subset \overline{B_2(0,r)}^{\| \cdot \|_1}$. As such we can write, $B_1(0,1) \subset B_2(0,r)+B_1(0,\frac{1}{2})$ and upon rescaling we have $B_1(0,\frac{1}{2^n}) \subset B_2(0,\frac{r}{2^n})+B_1(0,\frac{1}{2^n})$ for all $n \geq 1$. Select $y \in X$ such that $\|y\|_1 <1$, that is we can write $y=x_1+y_1$ where $\|x_1\|_2 <r$ and $\|y_1\|_1 < \frac{1}{2}$. Inductively we can choose a sequence of $y_n$ and $x_n$ such that $y_{n}=x_{n+1}+y_{n+1}$ and $\|x_{n+1}\|_2 < \frac{r}{2^n}$ and $\|y_{n+1}\|_1 < \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$. Since $(x_n)$ is absolutely convergent, the completeness of $X$ implies that there is an $x \in X$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i =x$ in the $\| \cdot \|_2$ norm. Since the identity is continuous, this means that the series also converges to $x$ in the $\| \cdot \|_1$ norm. A rearrangement of the $y_n$ yields the following result, $y=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_i +y_{n+1}$. Letting $n \rightarrow \infty$ shows that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i$ converges to $y$ in the $\| \cdot \|_1$ norm as well. That is $y=x$ and we have that $\| y\|_2=\| x \|_2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \|x_i\|_2 = 2r$. 
This means that $B_1(0,1) \subset B_2(0,2r)$, i.e. $\|y\|_2 \leq 2r\|y\|_1$ for all $y \in X$.

Comment: do you know the open map theorem? if you do, apply it to $id$.

Comment: strict inequality cannot hold for the norms because of $x=0$.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425663/equivalent-norms-in-banach-spaces-of-infinite-dimension