# Homogeneous Sobolev space is a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I am reading a book and I have some questions about the proof.  The book wants to show $H^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a Hilbert space iff $s<\frac{d}{2}$. $H^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the homogeneous Sobolev space. For the case $s\geq\frac{d}{2}$, he defines a norm $$N:u\to||\hat{u}||_{L^1(B(0,1))}+||u||_{H^s}$$
He says $H^s(\mathbb{R}^d,N)$ is a Banach space.If we assume that $H^s(\mathbb{R}^d,H^s)$ is also complete then by Banach's theorem, there would be a constant $C$ such that $N(u)\leq C||u||_{H^s}$.

Here is my question. How we know $H^s(\mathbb{R}^d,N)$ is a Banach space? I don't think it is easy to check, maybe there is some way but I don't know. And why the Banach's theorem can be applied here? I don't think it is a finite dimensional space.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am confused by a couple of things: 1) why do you say "if we assume is _also_ complete"? You just said it's Banach, hence complete. 2) (this might be just my ignorance but) which one is "Banach's theorem"? 3) homogeneous Sobolev spaces are not Banach, they actually don't even have a natural norm. Are you sure you are not referring to the usual Sobolev spaces? 4) If you care about $s < \frac{d}{2}$, why do we start with $s \geq \frac{d}{2}$? 5) What norm did you put on $H^s$?

Comment: The statement is when $s\geq d/2$ the space is not Hilbert. I wanna show it by contradiction so I assume it is Banach. The norms are different, one is N and the other is $H^s$. It is indicated in the bracket. The Banach theorem that the author refers I guess is the equivalence of norms in finite dimension space.

Comment: Ok. So, you are trying to prove that $(H^s(\mathbb R^d), \|\cdot\|_{H^s})$ is not Hilbert, but actually you are going to prove it is not Banach, while you _know_ $(H^s(\mathbb R^d), N)$ (which I assume is the usual Sobolev space, as opposed to the _homogeneous_ one) is Banach . How did you define the norm $\|\cdot \|_{H^s}$? I never heard such a theorem being referred to as "Banach's theorem" and definitely we are not dealing with finite-dimensional spaces, so my guess is that it is something else. Maybe you can double check in your source.

Comment: I am fairly sure that you are trying to use the [Open Mapping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis)) in [this way](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425663/equivalent-norms-in-banach-spaces-of-infinite-dimension). Still, I don't know when the hypothesis $s \geq \frac{d}{2}$ comes in, nor your definition of $(H^s(\mathbb R^d), \|\cdot\|_{H^s})$. If you tell me the book you're reading I can look up the notation you are using.

Comment: It is this book.http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-16830-7.  Sorry I don't have a pdf version of this book. If you have the book, it is the proof of prop1.34. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I am not sure what the author means by Banach's theorem, but it seems like the relevant result from functional analysis which he's using is the bounded inverse theorem: if $T:(X,\left\|\right\|_{X})\rightarrow (Y,\left\|\right\|_{Y})$ is a continuous (i.e. bounded) bijective linear map between two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$, then $T^{-1}: (Y,\left\|\right\|_{Y})\rightarrow (X,\left\|\right\|_{X})$ is a continuous (i.e. bounded) linear map. Note that the spaces don't need to be finite-dimensional, just Banach; if you don't know this result, you really should consult a text on functional analysis.

This result is used to obtain a contradiction, since if $T=I:(X,\left\|\right\|_{1})\rightarrow (X,\left\|\right\|_{2})$ is the identity map on $X$ and $\left\|\right\|_{1}$ and $\left\|\right\|_{2}$ are two norms on $X$ with respect to which $X$ is complete, then they are equivalent by the preceding result. The author derives a contradiction from this by exhibiting an example $u$ to show that there is no universal constant $C>0$ such that
$$\left\|\widehat{u}\right\|_{L^{1}(B(0,1))}\leq C\left\|u\right\|_{\dot{H}^{s}}$$
Here is the example. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the annulus $\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{d} : 1/4\leq\left|x\right|\leq 3/8\right\}$. Note that the annulus $2\mathcal{C}=\left\{1/2\leq\left|x\right|\leq 3/4\right\}$ is disjoitn from $\mathcal{C}$, and $\mathcal{C}\subset B(0,1)$. Define
$$\Sigma_{n}:=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{2^{n(s+\frac{d}{2})}}{j}\chi_{2^{-j}\mathcal{C}}\right)^{\vee}$$
Since $2^{-j}\mathcal{C}\cap 2^{-i}\mathcal{C}=\emptyset$, $i\neq j$, we have that
$$\left\|\widehat{\Sigma}_{n}\right\|_{L^{1}(B(0,1))}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{2^{j(s+\frac{d}{2})}}{j}2^{-jd}C=C\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{2^{j(s-\frac{d}{2})}}{j},$$
where $C=\left|\mathcal{C}\right|$, and
\begin{align*}
\left\|\Sigma_{n}\right\|_{\dot{H}^{s}}^{2}&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\left|\xi\right|^{2s}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{2^{j(s+\frac{d}{2})}}{j}\chi_{2^{-j}\mathcal{C}}(\xi)\right)^{2}d\xi\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\int_{2^{-j}\mathcal{C}}\left|\xi\right|^{2s}\left(\dfrac{2^{j(s+\frac{d}{2})}}{j}\right)^{2}d\xi\\
&\leq \sum_{j=1}^{n}2^{-2js}2^{-jd}\left(\dfrac{2^{j(s+\frac{d}{2})}}{j}\right)^{2}\int_{\mathcal{C}}d\xi\\
&=C\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{j^{2}}\leq C_{1}<\infty
\end{align*}
for all $n$. But since $s\geq d/2$, we see that $\left\|\widehat{\Sigma}_{n}\right\|_{L^{1}(B(0,1))}\uparrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, whence $N(\Sigma_{n})\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

---

To see that $(\dot{H}^{s}(\mathbb{R}^{d}),N)$ is a Banach space, let $(u_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence in $\dot{H}^{s}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ which is Cauchy with respect to $N$. The definition of $N$ implies that $\widehat{u}_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d};\left|\xi\right|^{2s}d\xi)$, which is complete, whence there exists an element $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d};\left|\xi\right|^{2s}d\xi)$ such that $(\widehat{u}_{n})$ converges to $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d};\left|\xi\right|^{2s}d\xi)$. Similarly, since $L^{1}(B(0,1))$ is complete, there exists an element $g\in L^{1}(B(0,1))$ such that $\widehat{u}_{n}$ converges to $g$ in $L^{1}(B(0,1))$.

I claim that $f=g$ a.e. on $B(0,1)$. To show this, we need the following simple lemma.

> **Lemma.** $\left|\xi\right|^{2s}d\xi$ and Lebesgue measure $d\xi$ (we'll also use notation $\left|\cdot\right|$) are mutually absolutely continuous.

*Proof.* Since $\left|\xi\right|^{2s}$ is nonnegative, it is evident that $\left|\xi\right|^{2s}d\xi$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. Conversely, suppose $\int_{A}\left|\xi\right|^{2s}d\xi=0$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$,
$$\int_{A}d\xi=\int_{A\cap B(0,\epsilon)}d\xi+\int_{A\setminus B(0,\epsilon)}d\xi\leq\int_{B(0,\epsilon)}d\xi+\epsilon^{-2s}\underbrace{\int_{A}\left|\xi\right|^{2s}d\xi}_{=0}\leq \left|B(0,1)\right|\epsilon^{d}$$
Letting $\epsilon\downarrow 0$ completes the proof. $\Box$

Since $\widehat{u}_{n}$ convereges to $f$ in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d};\left|\xi\right|^{2s}d\xi)$, passing to a subsequence if necessary, we may assume that $\widehat{u}_{n}\rightarrow f$ a.e. with respect to the measure $\left|\xi\right|^{2s}d\xi$. Similarly, since $\widehat{u}_{n}\rightarrow g$ in $L^{1}(B(0,1))$, passing to a further subsequence if necessary, we may assume that $\widehat{u}_{n}\rightarrow g$ (Lebesgue) a.e. on $B(0,1)$. The desired conclusion follows immediately from the above lemma.

We now use this result to show that the $L_{loc}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ function $f$ is a tempered distribution. Then we can define $u$ to be the inverse Fourier transform of $f$, and we will have shown that $u\in\dot{H}^{s}$ and $u_{n}\rightarrow u$ with respect to the norm $N$.

For any Schwartz function $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\left|f(\xi)\varphi(\xi)\right|d\xi&\leq\int_{B(0,1)}\left|g(\xi)\varphi(\xi)\right|d\xi+\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\left|\xi\right|^{s}\left|f(\xi)\right|\left|\varphi(\xi)\right|d\xi\\
&\leq\left\|g\right\|_{L^{1}(B(0,1))}\left\|\varphi\right\|_{L^{\infty}}+\left\|f\right\|_{L^{2}(\left|\xi\right|^{2s}d\xi)}\left\|\varphi\right\|_{L^{2}},
\end{align*}
where we use Holder's inequality in the last step. Both $\left\|\varphi\right\|_{L^{\infty}}$ and $\left\|\varphi\right\|_{L^{2}}$ are controlled by a finite sum of Schwartz seminorms, from which the conclusion follows.

Comment: A small remark, since there are different definitions of homogeneous Sobolev spaces flying around. To apply the inverse function theorem, we need an actual Banach space. So in particular, we need H^s to be a normed space. So taking the closure of smooth compactly supported functions should be fine, right?