# Proof of the equivalence of the norms in Banach spaces (infinite dimension)

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm confused about the common proof of the equivalence of the norms in Banach spaces. It was very clear and nice answered here [equivalent norms in Banach spaces of infinite dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425663/equivalent-norms-in-banach-spaces-of-infinite-dimension), but i still don't understand, why we can use identity map?

More precisely: Let $X$ be a Banach space and $i: (X, \|\cdot\|_2) \rightarrow (X, \|\cdot\|_1), x \mapsto x$ be the identity map on $X$ (i.e. $i(x)=x$ for all $x \in X$). It is given, that $\|x\|_2  \le C \|x\|_1, C > 0$. Then $i$ is continuous, since $\|i(x)\|_1=\|x\|_2  \le C \|x\|_1$ (by assumption).

The only question is: why it does not means, that $\|x\|_1=\|i(x)\|_1=\|x\|_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why should you be able to conclude that $||x||_1=||x||_2$? This is just not true. Consider $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ with $||\cdot||_1=||\cdot||_{L^1}$ and $||\cdot||_2=||\cdot||_{L^\infty}$. Then these norms are equivalent (in particular, both identity maps are continuous) but not identically equal.

Comment: My confusion comes from the fact, that $i(x)=x$. Then if we know that $\|i(x)\|_1=\|x\|_2$ and if we can write instead of $i(x)$ just its value ($x$) then $\|x\|_1=\|i(x)\|_1=\|x\|_2$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: How do you know that $||i(x)||_1 = ||x||_2$?

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets, I know it, since by definition $i$ maps from one normed space (with the norm $\| \cdot \|_2$) to another normed space (with the norm $\| \cdot \|_1$). But why we can not take a value of $i(x)$ inside of  $\| \cdot \|_1$, when $i$ is identity? I know, that it is maybe a very stupid argument, but I don't see any contrdiction, or an argument, why we can not to do so...

Comment: Don't think of these as the same space. They are not. Just because $i$ maps identically on the elements, does not mean that $i(x)\in (X, ||\cdot||_2)$. This is not true. What is true is that $i(x)\in (X, ||\cdot||_1)$ and $x \in (X, ||\cdot||_2)$. Think of it like this: $i((x, ||\cdot||_2))=(x, ||\cdot||_1)$